# How to save Spark Dataset to Bigquery Table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Has anyone experience saving Dataset to Bigquery Table?

I am loading into BigQuery using the following [example](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/examples/bigquery-connector-spark-example) sucessfully. This uses RDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset method to save data. 
I am using Dataset(or DataFrame) and looking for saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset method but unable to find it.

Any example would be brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [spark-bigquery](https://github.com/spotify/spark-bigquery#spark-bigquery) it has a method `dataframe.saveAsBigQueryTable`:

```
df.saveAsBigQueryTable("my-project:my_dataset.my_table")
```

Comment: And how to do it in pyspark? :)